# How to reduce the size of google spreadsheet using SQL?

Tags: mysql, excel, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which is about 9MB in size and I want to reduce its size using SQL.
What are the possible ways to reduce Spreadsheet's size if I cannot use SQL?

Comment: This question makes no sense.   You might as well ask if you can change the colour of an apple using a wombat.

Comment: Select all.   Delete.  That would reduce its size dramatically.

Comment: Have you tried hitting the apple very hard with the wombat, they both tend to change colour.

Comment: wombats eat cheez burgers ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the Format menu there's an option for Font Size - by default this is set to 10 but if you make it smaller you can reduce the size of the spreadsheet.

Or as recommended by Neil you can delete some/all of the data.